# I cannot find any attribute of "Grid Layout" in Android Studio 3.5 although, I have already downloaded and added it library?

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-studio-3.5

I cannot find any attribute of "Grid Layout" in Android Studio 3.5 although, I have already downloaded and added it library ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in legacy option in palette. Go to legacy option, then to grid layout and it will ask you to download the grid layout. Hence, you can use it.
[you can see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41UlE.png)